# How to export AWS SDK in linux cmd(try to compile java in linux)

Tags: java, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, classpath

I have some java files and I want to run them in the linux cmd mode. In those java files I used aws java sdk, so I need to set the classpath for aws java sdk. Here is what I did:

```
export CLASSPATH=/home/ubuntu/loadbalancer/aws-java-sdk-1.10.20/lib/aws-
java-sdk-flow-build-tools-1.10.20.jar:/home/ubuntu/loadbalancer/aws-java-
sdk-1.10.20/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.10.23-sources.jar:/home/ubuntu
/loadbalancer/aws-java-sdk-1.10.20/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.10.20.jar:
/home/ubuntu/loadbalancer/aws-java-sdk-1.10.20/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.10.20-
javadoc.jar:/home/ubuntu/loadbalancer


echo $CLASSPATH /home/ubuntu/loadbalancer/aws-java-sdk-1.10.20/lib/aws-
java-sdk-flow-build-tools-1.10.20.jar:/home/ubuntu/loadbalancer/aws-java-
sdk-1.10.20/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.10.23-sources.jar:/home/ubuntu
/loadbalancer/aws-java-sdk-1.10.20/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.10.20.jar:
/home/ubuntu/loadbalancer/aws-java-sdk-1.10.20/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.10.20-
javadoc.jar:/home/ubuntu/loadbalancer
```

When I did `javac *.java`
I got this stack trace

```
javac *.java
LoadBalancer.java:15: package com.amazonaws.auth does not exist
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
^
LoadBalancer.java:16: package com.amazonaws.services.ec2 does not exist
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client;
^
LoadBalancer.java:17: package com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model does not exist
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.CreateTagsRequest;
```

Anyone could help?

Answer (score 0):

**Side question**: Is there a specific reason why you cannot do this through a proper dependency management system? (for example: maven).

What the error are telling you is that parts of your app are referencing things that are not in the classpath.

Are the jars that you've put in the classpath actually at that location? i can see at least 1 problem in /home/ubuntu/loadbalancer/aws-java-
sdk-1.10.**20**/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.10.**23**-sources.jar

Comment: Thanks for responding. I found my problem, I did not import all the jar files into the classpath. The difference for jar file and path was a good catch!

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem, I did not import all the jar files into the classpath.